# Most efficient jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Which of the following selectors is most efficient in jQuery? Or is there any real difference?

1. `input[type=text]`
2. `[type=text]`
3. `input:text`
4. `:text`

Of course, an ID selector on the element would be best because the interpreter can use `getElementById()`, but I'm trying to understand the general differences in the above selectors.

Comment: http://jsperf.com will answer all your questions.

Comment: You forgot `input:text` which is what I would use...

Comment: Do you provide context? ...as in `$( 'input:text', form )`

Comment: Thanks, Šime. I added it to the list.

Comment: Also, values of attribute selectors are required to have quotes... like `[type="text"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick [test case](http://jsperf.com/jq-text-sels) I set up (note that I've added the necessary quotes around the attribute name selectors). It looks like the first method is fastest, which is expected really (because the others imply a universal `*` selector), followed by `[type='text']`, and in last place is `:text`.

In reality, the difference is so minimal it doesn't really matter which you choose.

Here's a screenshot (edit - I've added in the 4th method after seeing the update to the question):

[image]

Comment: You added the "necessary quotes." Are they necessary for performance (the selector works with or without them)?

Comment: See the jQuery docs... "Quotes are mandatory" - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down:

```
input[type=text]
// and
[type=text]
```

Are both [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). The first one being faster because the lookup of the attribute is already narrowed down to input elements.

```
input:text
:text
```

Are jQuery extensions. From the [:text selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/):

> Because :text is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :text cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="text"]
>   instead.

So these selectors are slower (whereas narrowing it down to input elements will be faster here as well).